# Add Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to develop for Android ... I downloaded eclipse, I have ADT and SDK installed properly but when I do file> new, I can not find the item Android project... may be added after installing the ADT.
Can you tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly installed the ADT plugin, just restart eclipse once and then also if it is not appearing try `file->new->other` , select android folder and there you will get the android project item.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Eclipse then look at Kumar Kl answer:

If U have installed ADT properly means , Just restart the eclipse once and then also if it s not appearing . file->new->other , select android folder ther u will get the android project item.